# How to obtain related cell in microsoft access

Tags: formula

Is there anyway to obtain a related cell in Microsoft Access? I'm working on a training database, and I need certain information to be tied together. For instance if an employee works for a certain department, I need that information to always go hand in hand.

I have several tables and unfortunately there does need to be some overlap. So for instance, the roster page will contain an employee's information including name and department, job title, etc. The table where their training will be entered will also have their name department, job title, etc. Is there any way that I can make it where you enter their name and it automatically pulls the info for department, job title, etc, based on what was entered in the roster?

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches to this.

1) Use the RecordSource builder button on the form you are using, and create a query that brings the 2 tables together on the field that relates them (i.e. EmployeeID, EmployeeNumber, etc.). This may result in a non-editable query which may still work for you though. You'll also want to double click the line connecting the 2 tables in the QBE (Query Design Window), and make sure to do a left join. On the AfterUpdate of the employee, you'll need to run a Requery of Refresh to run the query again.

2) Create a master form / subform scenario. Set the record source of each form to the correct table, and then use the MasterField and ChildField attributes on the parent form to "tell" Access how they relate. Access will automatically requery the subform when the current record on the parent form changes.

3) Create an AfterUpdate event on the Employee that fetches the value from the related table, and either displays in in an unbound way, or writes the information to the base table using VBA or an UPDATE query.

I can help you more if you can describe you situation a little more.

Kindest regards...